# jQuery AJAX POST request throws Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been having trouble getting a jQuery based POST request to work.

Line 20 throws this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier .

The buttons are generated with PHP and are as follows:

```
<a id="df-save-218281" 
  class="button js-saved-search"
  href="/realestate/addsearch/?s=-List+Price&amp;Town_State=Burlington+VT&amp;Description%5Blikeany%5D=five+sisters&amp;State=VT&amp;Status%5Bany%5D=ACT%2CUAG%2CPCG%2CPEN%2CRNT%2CA%2CK%2CL%2CO%2CR%2CT"
  data-alt-href="/realestate/removesearch/218281/"
  data-alt-text="Delete Search"
  data-toggle-class="remove">
  <span>Save Your Search</span>
</a>
```

And the Javascript is here:

```
$(function () {
  $('.js-saved-search').click(function(event) {
    console.log('clicked');
    event.preventDefault();

    var jsSavedSearch = $(this),
      queryString = decodeURIComponent(jsSavedSearch.attr('href')),
      url = jsSavedSearch.attr('href'),
      name = jsSavedSearch.text();
      id = jsSavedSearch.attr('id').replace(/\D/g, '');

      console.log(id);
      console.log(name);
      console.log(queryString);

    var posting = $.post( queryString, { SearchName: name } );

    posting.done(function( data ) {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(jsSavedSearch.attr('data-alt-text').replace(/\/\d+\//g, data));
      console.log(jsSavedSearch.text());
      console.log(jsSavedSearch.attr('data-alt-href'));
      console.log(jsSavedSearch.attr('href'));

      newText = jsSavedSearch.attr('data-alt-text');
      newAltText = jsSavedSearch.text();
      newHref = jsSavedSearch.attr('data-alt-href');
      newAltHref = jsSavedSearch.attr('href');

      console.log(newAltText);
      console.log(newText);
      console.log(newAltHref);
      console.log(newHref);

      jsSavedSearch.attr('data-alt-text', newAltText);
      jsSavedSearch.text(newText);
      jsSavedSearch.attr('data-alt-href', newAltHref);
      jsSavedSearch.attr('href', newHref);

    });
  })
});
```

**EDIT:**
The problem appears to be with this regular expression.  I am having trouble figuring out how to escape values in a JavaScript regex.

`newText = jsSavedSearch.attr('data-alt-text').replace(/\/\d+/\/g, data)`

Answer (score 2):

looks like you have `;` in place of `,` when defining the variable..

```
var jsSavedSearch = $(this),
  queryString = decodeURIComponent(jsSavedSearch.attr('href')),
  url = jsSavedSearch.attr('href'),
  name = jsSavedSearch.text();
  id = jsSavedSearch.attr('id').replace(/\D/g, '');
```

should be

```
var jsSavedSearch = $(this),
  queryString = decodeURIComponent(jsSavedSearch.attr('href')),
  url = jsSavedSearch.attr('href'),
  name = jsSavedSearch.text(), 
                      //-----^---here
  id = jsSavedSearch.attr('id').replace(/\D/g, '');
```

Comment: That probably isn't an issue though.. that's like saying `var a=0,b=1; c=3;` is not valid.. but it is - it will local scope `a` and `b` and make `c` global [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gySNX/)

Comment: bipen - Thanks for the help, unfortunately that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: where actually your line number 20 points too... check you console..

Comment: It turned out to be a problem with the regex I was trying to use.  I fixed it with the following code.  

` if( [0-9]+/i.test(data)) { newHref = newHref.replace(/[0-9]+/, data); } `